# A Real-Life Lethal Lava Land

Tags: science-fiction, environment, lava, video-games

Imagine for a moment, a video game lava level exactly like BotW's Eldin Region, or the eighth world in New Super Mario Bros: Wii. You know, flowing lavafalls and rivers, lava spewing mountains akin to volcanos and the occasional stone platform or rock to jump across the lava with.

Now imagine if you took one of these environments, shoved it into the real world (could be relegated to an island or slapped onto someplace with enough empty space to spare) and modified them to conform to reality's rules and physics system.

How exactly would one interact with this environment? obviously it would be far to hot to survive in without heat resistant clothing, but could you still jump on rocks like they were actual platforms? Would the ground be dense enough for you to walk on without falling through? Is sinking in the lava no longer possible? Would the volcano erupt more than a single time and would the combination of raining fireballs, a large shockwave and a pyroclastic cloud be too much too handle, even with the right kind of getup? Most importantly however, would this place stay a lethal lava land forever, or would the rules of lava and magma eventually lead to the environment cooling down and resembling a large, barren rocky island?

I'm only asking about how this environment would work in real life, not how to modify it into some kind of virtually reality video game level where I'm essentially the controllable character.

Comment: By "modified them to conform to reality's rules and physics system", do you mean that it would kill you from the radiant heat? (So it would *look* the same but not be "functional"?) Or that it's somehow it's been altered so that you could interact with it like a video game level?

Comment: What happens? It's your story, we don't write it for you.

Comment: Your edit seems to have added multiple opinion-based and story-based questions. We deal with one clearly focused question at a time here, please refer to the [help] for advice.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is probably going to get closed for being too broad. Consider what exactly you want to have answered? Like how to make a realistic lava area that people in your story can go through without dying?

There are real life places where lava pools and flows around, they are typically called volcanoes. Check out the image results here: https://www.google.com/search?q=hawaii+lava+fields

Video game / movie lava tends to ignore the fact that lava is really, really hot and makes likewise makes the air around it very hot, lethally so. Standing on a rock in the middle of a lava lake would kill you almost as fast as jumping into the lava directly.

If you notice from the image results, lava that is flowing tends to cool down and slow down as it gets further from its source.

So a realistic area where your characters can run and jump over lava will have cool, slow lava flowing that is mostly covered in newly formed rock.

The real danger will be stepping on what looks to be solid ground, but it collapses and drops you into lava that's slowly flowing beneath.

Comment: I'll modify the question so that it's a bit less broad and the people reading it will have a better idea what it is I am asking. Thx for answer it as best as you could though.

Comment: After thinking over things more thoroughly, I've come to the realization that no matter how hard I try, I'll never be able to obtain an answer to the questions I am asking, since they're derivative of problems that I have unintentionally created for myself due to my over the top desire for realism in unrealistic worlds. Because of this, I would like to request permission to delete this question, or edit it into an entirely different question (I'm asking because I know it's heavily advised to refrain from deleting questions that have already been answered by someone else/others)

Comment: I think your best bet is to just try making a new question? Either way, something to consider is that if you set your lava-fields on a volcanically active moon like Io. The extremely thin atmosphere means you could get closer to lava flows without heating up as quickly.

Comment: That's a cool bit of info. Setting my game on a planet different from Earth anyway so that might just work. Also what'll happen to this question if I just leave it and ask a new one? Will it just stay closed forever (still fairly new to this site)?

Comment: I've never actually asked a question here, but as far as I know that would be its fate, yeah.